# Modulus calculation for big numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, big-numbers

I am having problems with calculating
$$x \mod m$$

with
$$x = 2^{\displaystyle2^{100,000,000}},\qquad m = 1,500,000,000$$

I already found posts like this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers

But can someone explain me how to use this in my case, please?

Comment: Do we know what $m$ is?  We won't have a nice general formula in terms of $m$, if that's what you're looking for.  However, we can certainly solve this in the case that, for example, $m = 17$.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot that. I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [the Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) in addition to other bits.

Observe that your modulus factors like $m=2^8\cdot3\cdot 5^9$. Your number is very obviously divisible by $2^8$, so we can forget about that factor until the end.

Modulo $3$? The number $2^{2^{\text{ZILLION}}}$ is clearly a power of $4$, so its remainder modulo $3$ is equal to $1$.

Modulo $5^9$? Because $2$ is coprime with $5^9$ we can use the Euler totient function $\phi$.
We have $\phi(5^9)=(5-1)5^8=4\cdot5^8.$ Call this number $K$. We know from elementary number theory that $2^K\equiv1\pmod{5^9}$. Consequently also $2^N\equiv 2^n\pmod{5^9}$ whenever
$N\equiv n\pmod{K}$. Therefore we want to calculate the remainder of $M=2^{100000000}$ modulo $K$. Let's repeat the steps. $M$ is clearly divisible by $4$, so we concentrate on
the factor $5^8$. Euler's totient gives $\phi(5^8)=4\cdot5^7$. Clearly $100000000=10^8=2^8\cdot5^8$ is divisible by $4\cdot5^7$. This implies that $M\equiv 2^0=1\pmod{5^8}$.

Now we begin to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. We know that $M\equiv 0\pmod 4$ and
$M\equiv 1\pmod {5^8}$. The CRT says that these congruences uniquely determine $M$ modulo
$K=4\cdot5^8$. As $5^8\equiv1\pmod4$, we see that $3\cdot5^8+1$ is divisible by four. As it is clearly also congruent to $1\pmod{5^8}$ we can conclude that $M\equiv 3\cdot5^8+1=1171876\pmod K$.

This, in turn, means that
$$
2^M\equiv 2^{1171876}\pmod{5^9}.
$$
This exponent, finally, is small enough for square-and-multiply. I cheat and use Mathematica
instead. The answer is that
$$
2^{1171876}\equiv1392761\pmod{5^9}.
$$

Now we know every thing we need about the remainders:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2^M&\equiv0\pmod{2^8},\\
2^M&\equiv1\pmod3,\\
2^M&\equiv 1392761\pmod{5^9}.
\end{aligned}
$$
All that remains is to put these bits together by yet another application of CRT. Have you implemented those routines?

---

Edit: I did this run of CRT with Mathematica. Barring an earlier error (in the above calculations) the answer is that
$$
X=2^{2^{100000000}}\equiv 741627136 \pmod{1500000000}.
$$
The observations leading to this are:

- The integer $256$ has remainder $256\pmod {256}$ and $256\equiv1\pmod3$. Therefore CRT says that $X\equiv256\pmod{3\cdot256}$. Here $3\cdot256=768$
- Extended Euclidean algorithm tells us that $(-928243\cdot768+365\cdot5^9=1$. Consequently the integer $A=365\cdot5^9$ has remainder $0$ modulo $5^9$ and remainder $1$ modulo $768$. Similarly the integer $B=(-928243)*768$ is divisible by $768$ and has remainder $1$ modulo $5^9$.
- Therefore 
  $$X\equiv 256\,A+1392761\,B\pmod{1500000000}.$$ Calculating the remainder of that `small' number gives the answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. I was not able to completely calculate it myself, but your final result seems still to be wrong ([Wolfram Alpha Result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2**2**100000000%251500000000))

Comment: That's perfectly possible. I will recheck this when I find the time. Putting the CRT pieces together is error prone when I do it, because I don't do that stuff too often.

Comment: @TimJoseph I found the error, I had used the number 1171876 as an input to CRT in place of the correct number 1392761. Sorry about that. Recalculating... and now agrees with WA :-) I also added a few bits about running the CRT, so that my intermediate results become verifiable by others.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,
I would do repeated squaring:

$x_0 = 2\\
for\ i=1\ to\ 100000000\\
\quad x_i = x^2_{i-1} \bmod m\\
$

By induction,
since 
$x_0 = 2^{2^0}$,
$x_i = 2^{2^i}$.

Since $m$ is so large,
you would have to use
multiple-precision arithmetic,
although,
if you work with
64-bit integers,
double-word arithmetic would work.

I would recommend
looking for existing code
that would do this,
rather than writing your own,
unless that is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want to calculate $a^b\ mod \ m$ with $b$ and m are very large numbers and a and m are coprime. We can use an interesting result called [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):
$$ a^{\phi(m)} \ mod \ m=1$$

So now we reduce to problem to calculate $$ b\ mod \ \phi(m) $$ , because if $r=b\  mod \ \phi(m) $ then $$ a^b\  mod\  m = a^{q \phi(m) +r} \ mod\   m= (a^\phi(m))^q.a^r\  mod\  m = a^r\ mod\  m$$

Thus, the problem is reduced.

So in your exemple you have to calculate

- $\phi(1500000000000)$; use the Wikipedia URL above.
- and to answer the same problem for $x'=2^{1000}$ and $m'\phi(1500000000000)$ you have to calculate $\phi(\phi(1500000000000))$

And i will let you to do the rest of calculations.
This how to do it manually , but in the general case the calcul of $\phi$ is very hard!

Comment: Problem: $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod{m}$ is true only, if $a$ and $m$ are coprime. That is not the case here.

Comment: yes you're right! thanks